# CustomAdapter not displaying the arraylist items in the list

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap, custom-adapter

I am just fiddling around and trying to parse the JSON data from sample url into my app.After parsing i want to display item on a list .I am using custom adapter.List is showing up empty with no data inside.But debugging shows i am getting data successfully from url.Where is the problem??
**Edit1**(Debugging): Added this code (and then removed it) to see if hashmap objects are being added properly to ArrayList .There is no problem in adding HashMap objects to List.

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : blogPosts)
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet())
                    {
                        String key = mapEntry.getKey();
                        String value = mapEntry.getValue();
                        Log.v(TAG,"Debugging2" +key);
                        Log.v(TAG,"Debugging2" +value);
                    }
```

Here is the main_activity:

```
package blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainListActivity extends ListActivity {


    public static final int NUMBER_OF_POSTS = 20;
    public static final String TAG = MainListActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected JSONObject mBlogData;
    protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private final String   KEY_TITLE="title";
    private final String   KEY_AUTHOR="author";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        if(isNetworkAvaliable()){
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            GetBlogPostsTask getBlogPostsTask = new GetBlogPostsTask();
            getBlogPostsTask.execute();//calls Asynchronus class's doInbackGround
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_items), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvaliable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo= manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            isAvailable = true;
        }

        return isAvailable;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void handleBlogResponse()
    {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (mBlogData == null)
        {
            // TODO: handle errors
            updateDisplayForError();

        }
        else
        {
            try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts =
                        new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                title= Html.fromHtml(title).toString();//check escape characters
                String author = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
                author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();

                HashMap<String,String> blogPost=new HashMap<String,String>();
                blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE,title);
                blogPost.put(KEY_AUTHOR,author);
                blogPosts.add(blogPost);//addding hashmap object to arraylist

            }
               String[] keys={"KEY_TITLE","KEY_AUTHOR"};
                int [] ids={android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
                SimpleAdapter adapter =new SimpleAdapter(this,blogPosts,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,keys,ids);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught", e);

        }
    }
    }

    private void updateDisplayForError() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.error_title));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.error_message));
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog dialogue=builder.create();
        dialogue.show();
        TextView emptyTextView= (TextView) getListView().getEmptyView();
        emptyTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_items));
    }

    private class GetBlogPostsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void,JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            int responseCode = -1;
            JSONObject jsonResponse=null;
            try {
                URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=" + NUMBER_OF_POSTS);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    int nextCharacter; // read() returns an int, we cast it to char later
                    String responseData = "";
                    while(true){ // Infinite loop, can only be stopped by a "break" statement
                        nextCharacter = reader.read(); // read() without parameters returns one character
                        if(nextCharacter == -1) // A return value of -1 means that we reached the end
                            break;
                        responseData += (char) nextCharacter; // The += operator appends the character to the end of the string
                    }

                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseData);
                    String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
                    Log.v(TAG, status);

                    JSONArray jsonPosts = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++)
                    {//just for debugging
                        JSONObject jsonPost = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = jsonPost.getString("title");
                        Log.v(TAG, "Post " + i + ": " + title);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);
                }


            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "URLException caught: "+e, e);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException caught: "+e, e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: "+e, e);
            }

            return jsonResponse;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
            mBlogData=result;//This class is a bridge between AsyncTask class and Main
            handleBlogResponse();

        }
    }



}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
09-22 21:09:09.910  11081-11081/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-22 21:09:09.954  11081-11091/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
09-22 21:09:09.955  11081-11091/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
09-22 21:09:10.067  11081-11110/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-22 21:09:10.106  11081-11081/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
09-22 21:09:10.209  11081-11110/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
    Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
09-22 21:09:10.216  11081-11110/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-22 21:09:10.302  11081-11110/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-22 21:09:15.607  11081-11096/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.419ms
09-22 21:09:16.618  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ ok
09-22 21:09:16.618  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 0: Asset Workflow for Game Art: 3D Modeling
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 1: New Course Roundup: JavaFX, WooCommerce, Java Loops and The CSS calc() Function
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 2: Mastering Meetups for Maximum Merriment
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 3: The 10 Most Influential Figures in Web Design
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 4: Jeanne Learned Swift and Used Her Free Time to Create and Launch a Unique iPhone App
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 5: New Course Roundup: Foundations for Apps, Drupal, 3D Art with Maya LT, Future Insights Live and More
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 6: Keeping Up With Java
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 7: Ricky is a High School Senior With a Successful Freelance Web Design and Development Business
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 8: Your First Job May Not Be Your Dream Job
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 9: Ultimate Guide to User Feedback Part 2: 10 Ways to Get User Feedback
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 10: Creating Customized Shelf Buttons and Hotkeys in Maya LT
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 11: The Scrum Sniff Test
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 12: 15-Year-Old Harry Learned to Code, Gained Industry Experience and is Well on His Way to a Future in Tech
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 13: How to Use Image Effects in Unity
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 14: New Course Roundup: Functional Python, Tkinter, Ruby, WordPress and More
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 15: What Every Junior iOS Developer Needs to Know
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 16: Go Back to School With Treehouse
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 17: How to be a Resourceful Indie Game Developer
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 18: New Course Roundup: How to Make a Video Game and Express Basics
09-22 21:09:16.619  11081-11108/blogreader.com.example.android.blogreader V/MainListActivity﹕ Post 19: Learn Game Development at Treehouse!
```

Comment: are you using emulator?

Comment: Where is your SimpleAdapter class

Comment: @Aakash I am using my physical device.Emulator is too slow.I tried GenyMotion its good but i like my device better.

Comment: try reconnecting your device

Comment: @Ajit Do i have to implement SimpleAdapter Class of my own?Last time i heard I needed to pass context,data,layout to it thats it.Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Aakash I tried it several times,its of no use

Comment: Please post adapter code as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line

```
onContentChanged();
```

after

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This will force your Activity to update the list, since it's content changed.

Comment: Sorry i am still getting an empty list.

Comment: Finally solved it.It was under my nose all the time!!!.So silly mistake.I added additional " " on already string types KEY_AUTHOR and KEY_VALUE.As a result key and value parameter passed to SimpleAdapter messed up which as a result showed Empty list as Adapter could not understand the key,value pairs.Thank you folks for your time!!!.